# Get count of distinct values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, distinct

I have a table with 23 total rows. One of the columns is called `thing`. There are only 11 distinct things out of the 23 total rows.

When I run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT thing FROM tablename WHERE condition
```

I correctly get 11 rows.

However, when I run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(thing) FROM tablename WHERE condition
```

I get 23 for the total count. However, I want to get 11, which is the count of the distinct things. How can I rewrite my query so that it gives me a total count of 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT thing) FROM tablename WHERE condition
```